# Firefox странное поведение плагина inputTags при перезагрузке страницы кнопкой браузера

Tags: javascript, firefox

Вопрос такой. на странице есть плагин inputTags, ввод тегов пользователя. Только в этом браузере, после кнопки обновить. Количество тегов отрисованных в плагине увеличивается вдвое. В хроме все в порядке.
Ларавель 6.20.2
php 7.4.4
не думаю что это имеет значение, возможно чего что не учитываю. Как может перезагрузка, добавлять к переменным вью значения. Ведь в контроллере они инициализируются "пустыми"
просто контроллер, получение данных, вывод вью, во вью плагин
Буду благодарен за идеи

Comment: нужен пример в песочнице например

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому то поможет. Кнопка обновить страницу в файрфоксе это location.reload вопрос был в кеше, содержимое страницы бралось из кеша, в результате в блок с тегами просто дописывалось еще раз его содержимое. location.reload(true) решает вопрос.